# Error in recursive feature elimination with caret

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to use caret for variable selection and I get an error at the same point with some types of models.  I reproduce below one error: "Error in { : task 1 failed - subscript out of bounds" but I also with other data get "Error in { : task 1 failed - "replacement has XXX rows, data has YYY"".

I am interested in solving this particular error and also suggestions for how one might approach debugging this.  Thanks.

```
library(caret)
data(iris)

predictors <- names(iris)[names(iris)!="Species"]

split <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = .8, list = FALSE)
irisData <- iris[,predictors]
irisData$Class <- iris$Species

training <- irisData[ split, ]
testing  <- irisData[-split, ]

times <- 1
folds <- 5
prednumSeq <- seq(1, length(predictors)-1, by = 1)

ctrl <- rfeControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                  timingSamps = 2,
            number = folds,
            repeats = times,
            saveDetails = TRUE,
                  verbose = TRUE,
            allowParallel = FALSE)

rfRFE <- rfe(training[,predictors],
                training$Class,
                sizes = prednumSeq,
                rfeControl = ctrl)
```

This results in:

```
+(rfe) fit Fold1.Rep1 size: 4 
-(rfe) fit Fold1.Rep1 size: 4 
+(rfe) imp Fold1.Rep1 
+(rfe) fit Fold2.Rep1 size: 4 
-(rfe) fit Fold2.Rep1 size: 4 
+(rfe) imp Fold2.Rep1 
+(rfe) fit Fold3.Rep1 size: 4 
-(rfe) fit Fold3.Rep1 size: 4 
+(rfe) imp Fold3.Rep1 
+(rfe) fit Fold4.Rep1 size: 4 
-(rfe) fit Fold4.Rep1 size: 4 
+(rfe) imp Fold4.Rep1 
+(rfe) fit Fold5.Rep1 size: 4 
-(rfe) fit Fold5.Rep1 size: 4 
+(rfe) imp Fold5.Rep1 
Error in { : task 1 failed - "subscript out of bounds"
```

Details from sessionInfo() are:

```
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] MASS_7.3-26        randomForest_4.6-7 e1071_1.6-1        class_7.3-7       
 [5] pROC_1.5.4         caret_5.15-61      reshape2_1.2.2     plyr_1.8          
 [9] lattice_0.20-15    foreach_1.4.0      cluster_1.14.4    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 compiler_3.0.0  grid_3.0.0      iterators_1.0.6 stringr_0.6.2  
[6] tools_3.0.0
```

Comment: Try `options(error = recover)` and see if you can spot the offending line.